# ScriptManager breaks upon publishing to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I am using the `ScriptManager` object with the `UpdatePanel` in my project. I have tested this project many times in Debug mode but as soon as I publish the page to IIS the site is unable to find the scripts. The scripts appear in my `Script` folder but when I click the link created by the `ScriptManager` I am given a 404. I am assuming that this is possibly cause by the fact that I am not creating my links dynamically.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.searchBut, searchBut.GetType(), "jquery", "     <script src=\"/Scripts/DataTables-1.10/jquery.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", false);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.searchBut, searchBut.GetType(), "datatables", "     <script src=\"/Scripts/DataTables-1.10/jquery.dataTables.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", false);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.searchBut, searchBut.GetType(), "jquery ui", "<script src=\"/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", false);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.searchBut, searchBut.GetType(), "baloons", "<script src=\"/Scripts/jquery.balloon.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", false);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.searchBut, searchBut.GetType(), "index", "<script src=\"/Scripts/index.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", false);

ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(searchBut);
```

**Update:**

This is what my script tags look like after they are created by the server.

```
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/Scripts/jquery.balloon.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/Scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: How does the `script` tag look like in the page and what is the url of your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debug may have worked fine under Visual Studio's built-in webserver, but if you change your project settings to use IIS instead, you'll have the same problem. You need to qualify your script path to make it relative to the web application. For example:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.searchBut, searchBut.GetType(), "jquery", "     <script src=\"" + Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath + "/Scripts/DataTables-1.10/jquery.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", false);
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for. I am not super familiar with ASP.net I assumed it was something just like what you mentioned.